# what is the Error i am getting while training the NMT Model?

Tags: django-modeltranslation, opennmt

When i Try to train my model with the below code:

**!onmt-main --model_type Transformer --config train_files/config.yml --auto_config train --with_eval**

[Error Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCpAU.jpg)

then facing this error.

**TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable**

2023-03-09 19:35:44.078617: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-03-09 19:35:44.073000: W runner.py:211] No GPU is detected, falling back to CPU
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Scripts\onmt-main.exe_*main**.py", line 7, in 
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opennmt\bin\main.py", line 325, in main
runner.train(
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opennmt\runner.py", line 213, in train
config = self._finalize_config(
File "C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\opennmt\runner.py", line 130, in _finalize_config
"average_loss_in_time", config["train"]["batch_type"] == "tokens"
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3R6f.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQ5i0.png)

Comment: kindly help me in this regard.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-ot-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) to see how you can improve your question.